# Embedding a subplot in ggplot (ggsubplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to recreate this base-produced plot with ggplot, but I want to use a workflow more elegant than the the one  [demonstrated here](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/ggplot2-plot-inside-a-plot/), which relies directly on `grid::viewport()`.

[image]

Using **ggsubplot**, I tried:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggsubplot)
d = data.frame(x = sort(rlnorm(300)), y = sort(rlnorm(300)), grp = 1)
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 10)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 10)) +
  geom_subplot(data=d, aes(x=5, y=1, group = grp, subplot = geom_point(aes(x, y))), width=4, height=4)
```

which produced the following disappointing result:

[image]

Obviously needs some work, but if axes, labels and grid are added to the subplot its not far off.  Any idea how to do these?  I can't find any examples of this, and ggsubplot defaults to removing these elements.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used the `viewport` in combination with ggplot, I was not even aware of `ggsubplot`

Comment: try the last example in `?annotation_custom`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [It is possible to create inset graphs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219671/it-is-possible-to-create-inset-graphs)

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041246/how-to-add-an-inset-subplot-to-topright-of-an-r-plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might have to play with position and color, etc, but it seems like adding `reference` works

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 10)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 10)) +
  geom_subplot(data=d, aes(x=5, y=1, group = grp, subplot = geom_point(aes(x, y))), width=4, height=4,reference=ref_box(fill = "grey90", color = "black"))
```

works

Comment: Thanks Ananta. This is the closest to what I requested so I feel obliged to award the solution. But I think Josh is right that the grid solution seems more elegant if you want a more professional looking subplot of this kind (given ggsubplot's insistence on minimising subplot chart elements).

Comment: Note that as of 2019 geom_subplot and the ggsubplot package are dead and no longer available on CRAN. The working solution is now to use annotation_custom() as described in another answer by baptiste.

Answer (score 15):

With cartesian coordinates, I would use `annotation_custom`

```
require(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(x = sort(rlnorm(300)), y = sort(rlnorm(300)), grp = 1)

main <- ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + theme_bw() 

sub <- main + geom_rect(data=d[1,],xmin=0, ymin=0, xmax=5, ymax=5, 
                        fill="blue", alpha=0.5)
sub$layers <- rev(sub$layers) # draw rect below

main + annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(sub), xmin=2.5, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=2.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 5)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you had in mind?

**Edit:** Added @geotheory's edit to draw only 1 `geom_rect(...)`

[image]

You can do this with `viewports` in the `grid` package.

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
d   <- data.frame(x = sort(rlnorm(300)), y = sort(rlnorm(300)), grp = 1)
ggp <- ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 5)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 5)) 

sub <- ggplot(d)+geom_point(aes(x,y))+
  theme_bw()+
# assign single row data object so only one rectangle is drawn  
  geom_rect(data=d[1,],xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=5,ymax=5,fill="blue",alpha=0.5)

library(grid)
grid.newpage()
print(ggp)
vp <- viewport(width = .6, height = .6, x=.37, y=.06,just=c("left","bottom"))
pushViewport(vp)
print(sub,vp=vp)
```

Comment: @Ananta - Yes he did, though it's pretty poor practice to supply critical info like that in the form of a link that readers have to click through to to pick up. Ended up wasting a bit of jlhoward's time. (& FWIW, using **grid**'s mature, expressive toolset to do this seems like the **more** elegant approach to me.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, yeah, I also commented in OP's question for viewport and clicked in link before answering, he might have used "rather than viewport" to save our time.

Comment: @Ananta -- It wasted a bit of my time as well. I just edited the question to make the OP's request a bit clearer.

Comment: Apologies for not being more explicit.  I think the comments above are right that grid currently remains the more elegant solution.

Comment: @josh-obrien can you suggest any SO guidance on the linking to external sites? It seems pretty common in SO to find links to other questions that aren't described, requiring the same effort to follow. I personally fail to see the difference, but would be interested if this has been documented.

Comment: @geotheory -- Sorry if that came across sounding too harsh. Links are great, and my edits to your question pretty much show what I'd have preferred to have seen. As for what other SO questions do, I'd suggest keeping your standards *far* above those of the typical questioner here (as you already do ;). Cheers.

Comment: Point taken! Thanks for the feedback.