# Align inset in matlab plot to the right

Tags: matlab, plot, alignment, insets

How can I align an inset of a MATLAB plot to the top right edge of the box, like in the picture?

[image: Example in Gnu R]

The example was generated with GNU R as explained in [How to add an inset (subplot) to "topright" of an R plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041246/how-to-add-an-inset-to-topright-of-an-r-plot?rq=1)

Comment: So did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it:

Basically create a figure with an axes, and then add a new axis that you place to a specific position and to which you give the size you want.

Code:

```
clc
clear
close all

%// Dummy data
x = -20:0;
x2 = x(5:10);
%// Zoomed region to put into inset.

y = x.^2;
y2 = y(5:10);

%// Create a figure
hFig = figure(1);

%// Plot the original data
hP1 = plot(x,y);

xlabel('Original x','FontSize',18)
ylabel('Original y','FontSize',18)

hold on

%// Add an axes and set its position to where you want. Its in normalized
%// units

hAxes2 = axes('Parent',hFig,'Position',[.58 .6 .3 .3]);

%// Plot the zommed region
plot(x2,y2,'Parent',hAxes2)

%// Set the axis limits and labels

set(gca,'Xlim',[x(5) x(10)])
xlabel('Zoomed x','FontSize',16)
ylabel('Zommed y','FontSize',16)
```

And output:

[image]

To be fancy you could play around with the new axes position so that the outer borders coincide with the large one, but that should get you going :)

Comment: Thank you for the nice example, but when talking about alignment I thought about coincident alignment, not just parallel...

Comment: Ok. In your original question that was not the case/specified. I'll edit my answer