# R Plot, Layout -> plot two in second element

Tags: r, layout, plot

I am trying to plot three graphs. The first graph should occupy the whole frame. The second graph should be plotted on the top right corner and the third should be plotted on top of the second graph. Example for the first two plots:

```
mat <- layout(
matrix(c(1,1,2,1),2,2),
widths=c(1,1),
heights=c(1,1))
par(mar = c(5,4,4,4) + 0.1)
plot(0:-10)
par(mar = c(5,5,6,6))
plot(0:20)
```

Now I would like to plot the third graph on the second plot (i.e. plot other data on/in the small top right corner), but as I use e.g.

```
plot(0:10)
```

again, the third plot occupies the whole frame (actually as expected). How do I get the third plot on top of the second plot?

Comment: I think that you are asking for an inset plot.  The answers to [THIS previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17041246/4752675) show several ways to make insets