# How to add miniature to plot and repeat this for multiple plots side by side?

Tags: r, plot

There's a [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17042397/6574038) around to plot a miniature plot within a plot. I wrapped it in a function which works fine for a single plot.

```
myPlot <- function(x, y) {
  # main plot
  plot(x)
  # calculate position of inset
  pp <- par("plt")
  x0 <- pp[2] - (pp[2] - pp[1]) * 0.225
  x1 <- pp[2] - .01
  y0 <- pp[4] - (pp[4] - pp[3]) * 0.225
  y1 <- pp[4] - .01
  # set position for inset
  op <- par(fig=c(x0, x1, y0, y1), mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0), new=TRUE)
  # add inset grey background
  plot.new()
  u <- par("usr")
  rect(u[1], u[2], u[4], u[3], col="grey80")
  # add inset
  par(new=TRUE)
  plot(y, col=2)
  par(op)
}

myPlot(x, y)
```

[image]

However, when I use`Map` to loop over several data lists, in order to make multiple plots of this type side by side, there seems to be a mess with the `par`s. The miniature appears as a new plot and not within the main plot. Also a new device is opened after one iteration (i.e. old plot gets overwritten).

```
op1 <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
Map(function(x, y) myPlot(x, y), list(d0, d0), list(d0_inset, d0_inset))
par(op1)
```

[image]

When I use `Map(function(x, y) myPlot(x, y), list(d0, d0), list(d0_inset, d0_inset))` alone, though, there are two perfect plots in the plot queue (of RStudio). Thus the `plot.new()` and `par(new=TRUE)` might not be the issue here.

What I actually want is this:

[image]

`myPlot()` should throw a number of main plots with miniatures inside corresponding to the length of the data lists when using `Map` and fit it into the `par(mfrow=...)`.

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this using base R functionalities?

---

*Data:*

```
x <- data.frame(x = rnorm(150, sd=5), y = rnorm(150, sd=5))
y <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1500, sd=5), y = rnorm(1500, sd=5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of points here Jay. The first is that if you want to continue to use `mfrow` then it's best to stay away from using `par(fig = x)` to control your plot locations, since `fig` changes depending on `mfrow` and also forces a new plot (though you can override that, as per your question). You can use `plt` instead, which makes all co-ordinates relative to the space *within* the `fig` co-ordinates.

The second point is that you can plot the rectangle without calling `plot.new()`

The third, and maybe most important, is that you only need to write to `par` twice: once to change `plt` to the new plotting co-ordinates (including a `new = TRUE` to plot it in the same window) and once to reset `plt` (since `new` will reset itself). This means the function is well behaved and leaves the `par` as they were.

Note I have added a parameter, `at`, that allows you to specify the position and size of the little plot within the larger plot. It uses normalized co-ordinates, so for example `c(0, 0.5, 0, 0.5)` would be the bottom left quarter of the plotting area. I have set it to default at somewhere near your version's location.

```r
myPlot <- function(x, y, at = c(0.7, 0.95, 0.7, 0.95)) 
{
  # Helper function to simplify co-ordinate conversions
  space_convert <- function(vec1, vec2)
  {
    vec1[1:2] <- vec1[1:2] * diff(vec2)[1] + vec2[1]
    vec1[3:4] <- vec1[3:4] * diff(vec2)[3] + vec2[3]
    vec1
  }

  # Main plot
  plot(x)
  
  # Gray rectangle
  u <- space_convert(at, par("usr"))
  rect(u[1], u[3], u[2], u[4], col="grey80")
  
  # Only write to par once for drawing insert plot: change back afterwards
  plt <- par("plt")
  plt_space <- space_convert(at, plt)
  par(plt = plt_space, new = TRUE)
  plot(y, col = 2)
  par(plt = plt)
}
```

So we can test it with:

```
x <- data.frame(x = rnorm(150, sd = 5), y = rnorm(150, sd = 5))
y <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1500, sd = 5), y = rnorm(1500, sd = 5))

myPlot(x, y)
```

[image]

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
myPlot(x, y)
myPlot(x, y)
```

[image]

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
for(i in 1:4) myPlot(x, y)
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for the thorough explanation!

Comment: Fantastic approach to a problem I have long struggled with. I added this as a function to my package - allowing any plot to be embedded this way via `eval(expression()))` [link](https://github.com/marchtaylor/sinkr/blob/master/R/embedPlot.R)